# n-dash, m-dash missing on final print

Tags: pdftex

I use pdflatex (and I love texing).

New printer, new version of ubuntu, I no longer get any n-dashes and m-dashes on the final paper. All other punctuation seems to work: I get rules, lines, colons, dots, and (single) dashes.

They are typeset correctly: When I call up the pdf produced by pdflatex, it all looks as it's supposed to but
On the print, they are missing. Luckily (or maybe weirdly),  when I either 'preview' or 'print to file' I see the result as after printed, suggesting that it's not the printing swallowing these signs.
Problem occurs with both evince and xpdf. All classes, all font sizes.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

  \begin{document}
  \fbox{fbox}
-dash- n-dash-- m-dash--- colon: comma, dot.\\
\textsl{-dash- n-dash-- m-dash--- colon: comma, dot.}\\
\end{document}
```

gives us[image: evince above, preview below]

it's quite unnerving... any ideas? thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I'm assuming your TeX distribution is TeXLive. Did you notice any errors during the downloading and installation phases?

Comment: negative. I've had this on both my laptop and desktop

Comment: No problem here on Ubuntu 16.04 with Evince 3.10.3.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem, and it appears the problem is evince.

Just tried printing the same paper with Okular -- everything is fine! :)

Thanks to: https://medium.com/@lauradietz100/missing-dashes-and-hyphens-when-printing-pdf-d19bc4d2787c

Comment: thanks. still weird though.

Comment: I mostly use lpr or qpdf now.